# Spring Boot rendering index page after authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, controller

I have implemented SSO SAML using Spring Security. In my Spring Boot project I have the following controller which basically redirects a user to an idP login page it then generates a JWT token based on a successful login. This JWT token is then forwarded to the index page as a header. But I cant seem to get this to work properly.

Auth Controller,

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserAccountResource.class);

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    /**
     * Given that a user is already authenticated then generate a token
     *
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body of the updated {@link JWTToken} jwt token
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login")
    public String login(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        } else {
            try {
                final SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
                final DateTime dateTime = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion()
                        .getIssueInstant()
                        .toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()));
                String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, dateTime.getMillis(), false);
                response.addHeader(JWTConfigurer.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
                log.debug("Generated jwt {}", jwt);
                log.debug("SAMLCredential {}", credential);
                return "forward:/";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is as follows,

```
@Configuration("webConfigurer")
public class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

As far as SSO via SAML goes everything works great. The user gets redirected to the idP login e.t.c. What I cant figure out is why the `forward` isn't work as expected.

All my UI (Angular 4.x) is initiated with `index.html`.

When I tested this I can see it being forwarded to `/` however no headers come through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end is to separate the login and jwt generation to two APIs calls which worked great.

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String samlLogin() throws Exception {
    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Unable to get the SAML authentication information");
    } else {
        try {
            final SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
            if (credential == null) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException("Not valid SAML credentials");
            }
            return "forward:/";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(e);
        }
    }
}

@GetMapping("/jwt")
public ResponseEntity<String> generateJWT(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Unable to get the SAML authentication information");
    } else {
        try {
            final SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
            if (credential == null) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException("Not valid SAML credentials");
            }
            final DateTime dateTime = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion()
                    .getIssueInstant()
                    .toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()));
            String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, dateTime.getMillis(), false);
            response.addHeader(JWTConfigurer.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
            log.debug("Generated jwt {} for SAML authentication", jwt);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(jwt, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(e);
        }
    }
}
```